# Tokenize the string such that even the key words which have multiple words get extracted as one element of the array

Tags: javascript, regex, ruby, tokenize, text-processing

```
Input:(Google AND Microsoft OR Google Pixel AND NOT Apple IOS)
Desired Output:[(Google,AND,Microsoft,OR,Google Pixel,AND,NOT,Apple IOS)]
Ideal Output:[(Google,AND,Microsoft,OR,Google Pixel,AND NOT,Apple IOS)]
```

So, I want some kind of tokenizer or text extraction method to be applied on the Input to get any of the 2 outputs as mentioned below.

What I am currently using is a regex to tokenize words by " " and don't break words which have "''" (quotes around them)

Regex being used: `/'[^']*'|[^\s]+/` (PCRE)

```
Current Input:(Google AND Microsoft OR 'Google Pixel' AND NOT 'Apple IOS')
```

> This works because of the quotes around keyword with multiple words.

```
Current Output:[(Google,AND,Microsoft,OR,Google Pixel,AND,NOT,Apple IOS)]
```

Thanks.

Comment: Javascript or Ruby? They're pretty different languages. It also looks like your first input doesn't have any quotes anywhere..?

Comment: @CertainPerformance Am using Ruby but a js equivalent will also work for me, can convert the code. Also that’s how I want the input to be, that it shouldn’t have any quotes around it but it should still be able to recognise it as a single key word because of its position between ‘AND’ or ‘OR’ or ‘NOT’ operators.

Comment: Assuming that "AND", "OR" and "AND NOT" are fixed seperators you'll use in all of the strings you need to tokenize, just `.split()` ( javascript ) on those words and you get the ideal output.

Answer (score 1):

this worked for me:

```
'(Google AND Microsoft OR Google Pixel AND NOT Apple IOS)'
  .split(/(AND|OR|NOT)/)
  .map {|e| e.strip}
  .reject {|e| e.empty? }

=> ["(Google", "AND", "Microsoft", "OR", "Google Pixel", "AND", "NOT", "Apple IOS)"]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
str = "(Google AND Microsoft OR Google Pixel AND NOT Apple IOS)"
```

```
r = /( AND NOT | OR NOT | AND | OR )/
```

```
[str.gsub(r) { |s| ",#{s[1..-2]}," }]
  #=> ["(Google,AND,Microsoft,OR,Google Pixel,AND NOT,Apple IOS)"]
```

Note that in the regular expression `' AND NOT '` must precede `' AND '` and `' OR NOT '` must precede `' OR '`